# geocoding multiple addresses code behind

Tags: c#, geocoding

I am geocoding multiple address from an XML file to get the lat/lng to plot a marker on a map. It works fine with about 15 addresses but today I checked and there are 88 addresses and it takes a while to load the page. What's happening is a user clicks the link to the map page and the browser just spins until all the addresses have been geocoded, then the page loads. I'm having to use System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(150); before each call to the google service to avoid the query limit error. Is there anything I can do to make this load the page then load the addresses?

Comment: No matter the language, you should NEVER use `sleep()`

Comment: Brendan, what would you recommend?

Comment: Hold on, I'll come back after work.

Comment: When using 3rd party services that have a query limit, you should try to let client side scripts perform the requests. This way when one user is refreshing the page alot, the page will only stop working for that particular user. Dunno if this applies to your situation, though.

Comment: Don't hate on `sleep()`; it's not evil, but should just be used properly.

Comment: Could there be a way to load the page and show a busy indicator while the code behind processes? Right now it just sits on the page that is clicked and shows waiting on FF and after about 12 seconds it loads. Not a long time but you know how some people are.

Comment: Yes @user766595, see my answer below. If you still don't want the Javascript to do the processing, you *could* for some reason request your server to do it, and proxy the results back to your webpage. But no reason to keep the connection with the server open longer than necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've found, Google's geocoding service isn't for requests *en masse*. In fact, it's against their [terms of service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms) to use the service for bulk downloads or processing batch requests.

What you ought to look for is a service that doesn't have such low limits and allows you to submit batch requests to the API. For disclosure purposes, I work for [SmartyStreets](http://smartystreets.com), and we provide such an API called [LiveAddress](http://smartystreets.com/products/liveaddress-api).

It sounds like you're submitting as many requests as there are addresses to geocode and plot. 15-100 requests will take anywhere from one to maybe 10 or 15 seconds including network latency. I've seen your situation quite a few times in my line of work and it's a legitimate question.

What I'd recommend doing is having the server push down the page to the client, then have Javascript load the coordinates and plot the points. (C.Evenhuis suggested this in his comment.) While this will load the page earlier, it still should spin some sort of "Loading" animation, which will still make the user wait. Without an upgraded license with Google, your limits will remain.

To overcome this, you can look for an API that has a few key features:

- Geo-distributed. This reduces network latency and improves performance.
- Terms of service that allow you to perform batch requests or geocode *en masse*
- Support for multiple addresses per request, meaning you only have to submit one or two requests per page load, even for up to 100 or 200 addresses
- Preferably, a way to verify the addresses even exist before plotting them. Google approximates addresses, it doesn't verify them.
- Permission to cache/store the values for more than just a temporary amount of time for optimizing your scripts. Google's TOS won't let you store the results except only temporarily to optimize performance at runtime.

You can use LiveAddress as an example of what to look for, and see if it meets your needs. It supports up to 100 addresses per single request, so your wait time goes from several seconds to a few milliseconds. You can store the results you download basically indefinitely, and will only return coordinates for addresses that actually exist, or it will fix addresses that aren't quite correct. Let me know if you have any questions about it.

As a thought, even if you don't want the client-side to geocode the addresses, your C# code can do this and bundle all the addresses into one request.

[[Here's some sample C# code on GitHub](https://github.com/smartystreets/LiveAddressSamples/tree/master/c-sharp)]

Comment: I converted it to JavaScript like you suggested but either I'm doing something wrong or setTimeout is not working properly. I added a 5 second setTimeout and only a handful of the address geocode and the rest say "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT". I used this example: http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3/browse_thread/thread/e44e0785ee0772f1 and added a setTimeout on setTimeout("geocode('" + currentDetails + "', '" + currentProviderAddress + "', '" + i + "')", 5000); with some modifications.

Comment: As I mentioned, Google's free geocoding API doesn't support bulk geocoding. Even if you worked around it, it's against their terms of service. The reason you're probably getting that error, though, is because the `for` loop is still running asynchronously, queuing up geocoding requests which execute 5 seconds later, but all just milliseconds apart (if that).

Comment: That's exactly what is happening. For future coding, how would I stop it from running asynchronously?

Comment: Cross-domain requests aren't synchronous by nature, so you have to work around that. You might try using a static counter variable together with `setInterval` to simulate a synchronous, delayed `for` loop. `setInterval` will execute your callback function every `x` milliseconds. Declare `var i = 0`, for instance, outside `setInterval`. Increment it inside every time you do a geocode request, and turn off the interval when you've finished them all.